# Clearing a javascript button

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the 'Back to Top' button from codyhouse.co to provide a javascript button at the bottom right of all my site pages.

I am also using a javascript live chat/support button, which also appears in the bottom right of all site pages.

A problem I have is that they clash with each other. I have tried adjusting the CSS of the 'Back to Top' button to either make it clear the chat button and appear a level above or below on the right side, or to switch it to appear on the left. I have had no luck.

Following is the css:

```
/*top of page CSS*/
.cd-top {


  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #78BE20 url(../images/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible, .cd-top.cd-fade-out, .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
  /* the button becomes visible */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.no-touch .cd-top:hover {
  background-color: #e86256;
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-top {
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-top {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

I have tried adjusting the `bottom` and `right` values.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a link or a http://jsfiddle.net ? Or at least post the HTML too.

Comment: Or better yet, put the code in a snippet in the question itself. That way we're not relying on an external website.

Comment: Did you also modified the bottom and right in the media queries?

Comment: Thanks Jonas w I had forgotten to adjust the media queries too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shift left**

---

Do this to shift it left :

instead of : `right : 10px` change to `left : 10px`.

or by  whatever number of pixels you want to shift it to.

```
.cd-top {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #78BE20 url(../images/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
```

Also make  changes in media css  :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-top {
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-top {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

**Shift Up**

---

To shift up, just change the bottom values in `.cd-top` and media css :

```
.cd-top {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 140px;
  right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(232, 98, 86, 0.8) url(../img/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-top {
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 120px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cd-top {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 130px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu

This works. Also as per Jonas w's comment above, I had forgotten to adjust `bottom` and `right` in the media queries too